# Hyperic java api sample code

Tags: java, monitoring, hyperic

Has anybody used the HQAPI to fetch the metrics of a resource programmatically? I want a sample code which uses the HQAPI to fetch the metrics of a resource.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They seem to have plenty of examples on Github e.g.

https://github.com/hyperic/hqapi/blob/7b19d6b0ebfb8cfb2903d4a495ab0368ba3e6aeb/src/org/hyperic/hq/hqapi1/test/Metric_test.java

Also there is an example in their docs:

http://support.hyperic.com/display/DOC/HQApi+Java+API

Answer (score 2):

There is a treasure trove of examples here
http://svn.hyperic.org/projects/hqapi/trunk/src/org/hyperic/hq/hqapi1/test/

and I am trying to put together some explanation here
http://www.javamonamour.org/2012/05/creating-alert-recovery-with-hyperic.html

Answer (score 0):

The are actually a lot of ways you could do this:

1. Run the plain old hqapi.sh resource list (or like) commands, which could be very slow.
2. Paste directly in your browser window a restful URL:

   ```
   http://__host__:7080/hqu/hqapi1/alert/find.hqu?begin=1344004728555&end=1444004728999&count=100&severity=1&notFixed
   ```
3. Use curl to achieve that:

   ```
   curl -u hqadmin "http://__host__:7080/hqu/hqapi1/alertdefinition/listDefinitions.hqu?resourceId=10201"
   ```
4. I personally like using a scripting language like Python to do this.
5. Then there is Groovy script, which you can run in a Groovy console under the administration tab. Check the hqapi1 hqu plugin.